# what is the probability of a portion of pudding contains no sixpences？

Tags: probability, statistics

I am trying to solve the problem:
A cook makes three plum puddings for Christmas. He stirs r silver sixpences thoroughly into the pudding mixture before dividing it into three equal portions, portion A, portion B and portion C. Find an expression for probability that  portion A contains no sixpences.
So, I am thinking that portion A could contain 0,1,2,.....,r silver sixpences.As a result:

P(Portion A contains no silver sixpences)=
$$\frac{1}{r+1}$$

However, I have checked the mark scheme, it said that the probability should be:
$$(\frac{2}{3})^r$$

May I know why I am wrong? Thank you so much for you guys' replies.

Comment: The mark scheme seems to use a binomial distribution, with the probability $A$ contains $s$ sixpences being ${r \choose s}\left(\frac13\right)^{s}\left(\frac23\right)^{r-s}$.  This has expectation $\frac{r}3$ which is sensible.  You seem to use a uniform distribution  with the probability $A$ contains $s$ sixpences being $\frac{1}{r+1}$.  This has expectation $\frac{r}2$, which is not reasonable, since $B$ and $C$ presumably have the same expectation, and the three adding up to $\frac32 r$ rather than $r$.

Comment: Thank you very much, Henry.

Comment: Think about putting sixpence into $A$ as a failure and not putting it the success. You have $r$ trials, and probability of a success is $2/3$ as each outcome is equally likely. So, the probability of $r$ successes is $(2/3)^r$.